# My Masterpage uses a viewmodel that all my other models inherit from, how to simplify this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I use the model:

```
public void MasterViewModel
{
   public CurrentSession Session {get;set;}
}
```

And then all my other view models look like:

```
public void LoginViewModel : MasterViewModel
{

}
```

The problem is, I have to initialize my MasterViewModel in each and every action like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var model = new WelcomeIndexViewModel
  {
     Session = this.GetSession(); // from my base controller
  }

  ..
}
```

My basecontroller has the method `GetSession()`

**Is it possible to set this value in my basecontroller somehow so I don't have to do this in each action method?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could do, in your `BaseController` override `OnResultExecuting`, hijack the view model and inject the `Session` variable int, like this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (viewResult != null)
        {
            var viewModel = viewResult.Model as MasterViewModel;
            if (viewModel != null)
            {
                viewModel.Session = GetSession();
            }
        }
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Note: This is only checking if you use `return View(model);` in your controller, you might also check for other action results too (like partial views, json etc...)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a decorator function for the Controller.View function,
that would initialize the session for you.

Something like -

```
internal ActionResult ExtendedView(object model)
    {
        Session = this.GetSession();

        return View(model);
    }
```

Then, instead of using the return View(model), use return ExtendedView(model).